# how to hange the user in cacls using java appliacation without type on the syntax

Tags: java, file-permissions, cacls

i want to asking to u. i've tried these syntax in my project file, and it works.
 but, i wan to change these program to be more powerfull.

here my syntax:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    frame f = new frame();
    f.show();


    File f = new File("D:/lala/coba");

    //System.out.println("insert the username:");
   // hide(f);
}

public static  void hide(File src) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
// win32 command line variant
ProcessPerm p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cacls " + src.getPath() + " /E /C /P DINA:n");
p.waitFor(); }}
```

if i want to change the user "DINA" without write on the syntax, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the java application like
java Main scott

with the following code and the user will be scott

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    frame f = new frame();
    f.show();


    File f = new File("D:/lala/coba");

    //System.out.println("insert the username:");
   hide(f, args[0]);
}

public static  void hide(File src, String user) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
// win32 command line variant
ProcessPerm p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cacls " + src.getPath() + " /E /C /P " + user + ":n");
p.waitFor(); }}
```

Comment: thanks dude. i'll try it. if i found problem anymore, would you help me again?

Comment: Sure! if i' don't help you, there is always someone here better than me and ready to help you :P

Comment: well, i have tried your sugest syntax to me, but i'm confuse with String user and args[0]. can u tell me?

Comment: By now you already know that you are calling your java application as "java <class's complete package name> arg0 arg1 ... agrn". When you do this the main method of the class passed as argument is called.  <br/>At same time arg0, agr1 up to agrn are delivered to the  main method through the single parameter it has: String[]. In your example we are only passing one argument and it will be in available in the first array position [0] (arrays in java are zero-based).<br/> Then we just pass that value as a new argument for the method where we need it.